# Mocking objects for JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm writing a Junit to test the following method in Client.java:

```
public FSDataInputStream getObj(String hName, Path p) throws IOException {

    String myKey = pathToKey(hName, p);
    FileStatus status = memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString());
    if (status == null) {
      status = getStatus(hName, p, "getObject");
    }
    if (status.isDirectory()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't open " + path
      + " because it is a directory");
    }
    InputStream inputStream = new InputStream(bucket, myKey,
        status.getLen(), client, readAhead, inputPolicy);

    return new FSDataInputStream(inputStream);
}
```

Initially I want to test if `status == null` then `getStatus()` is invoked and if `status.isDirectory()`, the FileNotFoundException is thrown

I'm new to Junit so not completely sure what I'm at but to the best of my knowledge I think I need to mock the following:

1. List item
2. Client
3. status
4. inputStream
5. possibly memoryCache

So far this is what I've got:

```
@Before
public final void before() {
    private COSAPIClient myClient;
    private String myBucket;
    FileStatus myStatus;
    InputStream myInputStream;

    myClient = PowerMockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);
    myInputStream = PowerMockito.mock(InputStream.class);
    myFileStatus = PowerMockito.mock(FileStatus.class);
}

@Test
public void getObjTest() throws Exception {
    URI uri = new URI("xyz://aa-bb-cc/data7-1-23-a.txt");
    String hName = "xyz://aa-bb-cc/";
    Path p = new Path("cos://aa-bb-cc/data7-1-23-a.txt");

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    myClient = spy(new Client(uri, conf));
    myStatus = spy(new FileStatus());
    myMemoryCache.getStatus(p.toString());

    InputStream = spy(new InputStream(myBucket, objectKey, 300, myClient, 12345678910L, myInputPolicy));
}
```

It returns a NullPointerError at this line in my program:

```
FileStatus status = memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString());
```

I wonder is anybody could advice if/what I'm doing wronfg and how I should go about resolving this?

Comment: With _3. status_ you mean `getStatus()`?

Comment: What is `memoryCache`?  How is it initialized/injected into your class? Where do you invoke `getObj` into your class?

Comment: Clijsters -  Yes.
Sergii Bishyr - I'm not sure what you're asking but I'd be confident that what I'm doing is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the *real* answer: step back for a moment. Don't start with JUnit and Mockito and *your* production code as input. Rather have a look into a tutorial (like [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html)) that step-by-step explains all the relevant elements and how to "bring" them together.

In your case, the are various problems with your code:

- Why are you using PowerMock? Try to go with "plain vanilla" Mockito. If your production code is so that it requires PowerMock, rather consider to rework your production instead of turning to PowerMock.
- You seem to really not know where/how to apply mocking. In other words: you **only** mock the elements that you need to *control* when running your *code under test*. And you only use mocking, if you can't control them otherwise. Meaning: you almost never mock a list - you simply create a "normal" list to then add the things that this list should contain.
- Creating a mock allows to invoke methods on that mock object. But by default, any method that returns something will return null (or maybe an empty collection, or 0 for primitive return types, see [here](http://www.javarticles.com/2015/07/mockito-mock-objects-default-return-values.html) for details). Thus you rather need a statement such as `when(mockedCache.getStatus("some string")).thenReturn(someResult)`.

Comment: Nice explanation.  The third bullet point isn't quite right.  The default return value of a method on a mock depends on its return type - it doesn't always come back null.  There are a bunch of hard-to-remember exceptions, as follows.  A method that returns a `Collection` will return empty, not null by default.  A method that returns a primitive type will return 0 or false.  A method that returns a wrapper type for a primitive will also return 0 or false.  The standard `compareTo` method defaults to 1, and the standard `toString` method defaults to the name of the mock.

Comment: Thanks GhostCat. I'll check that out.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks. Didn't know that - I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that @GhostCat. I'll have to work at this a little but its very helpful.